# No module named Image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, django-grappelli

Sorry for my grammar, I don't speak English.
After I set filebrowser, tinymce, and grappelli, I get this error: `No module named Image`

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
```

I set it to `PIL` but it didn't solve the problem.
my platform windows

If i want: pip install PIL

```
`c:\Users\Kim\BitNami DjangoStack projects\homex8>pip install PIL
Downloading/unpacking PIL
  Running setup.py egg_info for package PIL
    WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py

Installing collected packages: PIL
  Running setup.py install for PIL
    WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py
    building '_imaging' extension
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`
```

I do not understand what that means

Solved problem.
reinstall PIL with easy_install, and more movements, here are [the details](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2010-August/006480.html).

Comment: Have you installed `PIL`? http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Comment: I think Python is case sensitive try "image"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you setup PIL module? [Link](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)

You can try to reinstall it on your computer.

Comment: @Homex what platform are you use?  linux or windows?

Comment: @Homex I don't know what do you mean with 'Or enough: pip install PIL?', you can install the `PIL-for-python.exe` download from [here](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) , try it . Good luck!

Answer (score 52):

You are missing PIL (Python Image Library and Imaging package). To install PIL I used

```
 pip install pillow
```

For my machine running Mac OSX 10.6.8, I downloaded Imaging package and installed it from source. 
http://effbot.org/downloads/Imaging-1.1.6.tar.gz and cd into Download directory.  Then run these:

```
    $ gunzip Imaging-1.1.6.tar.gz
    $ tar xvf Imaging-1.1.6.tar
    $ cd Imaging-1.1.6
    $ python setup.py install
```

Or if you have PIP installed in your Mac

```
 pip install http://effbot.org/downloads/Imaging-1.1.6.tar.gz
```

then you can use:

```
from PIL import Image
```

in your python code.

Comment: Thank you for Mac OS X hint. I tried various approaches with no luck. Building from source indeed helped.

Answer (score 7):

It is changed to : `from PIL.Image import core as image`
for new versions.

Answer (score 7):

You can this query:

```
pip install image
```

I had pillow installed, and still, I got the error that you mentioned. But after I executed the above command, the error vanished. And My program worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

```
~$ simple-image-reducer

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/bin/simple-image-reducer", line 28, in <module>
    import Image

**ImportError: No module named Image**
```

Reason:

Image != image

**Solution**:

1) make sure it is available

```
python -m pip install  Image
```

2) where is it available?

```
sudo find ~ -name image -type d
```

-->> directory /home/MyHomeDir/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/image
->> OK

3) make simple-image-reducer understand via link:

```
ln -s ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/image
~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Image
```

4)
invoke `simple-image-reducer`  again.
Works:-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just show the image on your notebook, below simply does the job

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image(url= "Link to the image ending with file format such as, .jpg or .png")
```