# View Picture in Python and Save User Input about that Picture

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Is there a way to have Python pull up a picture (that is stored locally) for a user to view and then have that user input information about that picture, which information is then stored locally?

I found some information about the Image library, but I can't get the Image library to work.  When I use the following code, I get an error:

```
import Image
```

ImportError: No module named Image

```
from PIL import Image
```

ImportError: No module named PIL

I tried to install pillow using

```
pip install pillow
```

I'm not sure if it installed correctly.  Any one else have this problem?  I'm  using Python 2.7.  I know that I can eventually use the following code to view the picture:

```
Image.open('example.jpg').show()
```

Comment: Did you try lowercase `import image`? That was suggested [elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024397/no-module-named-image) and worked when I tested it.

Comment: That didn't work.  I just found a .exe installer for pillow and that did the trick.  Thanks!