# About QRcode module

Tags: python, module

When I use `qrcode` module like this:

```
import qrcode

hello = qrcode.make("hello")

type(hello)
hello.save("test.png")
```

I get these errors and can't solve them:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qrcode/image/pil.py", line 5, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/./py", line 5, in <module>
    hello = qrcode.make("hello")
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qrcode/main.py", line 13, in make
    return qr.make_image()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qrcode/main.py", line 296, in make_image
    from qrcode.image.pil import PilImage
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qrcode/image/pil.py", line 7, in <module>
    import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'
```

I'm using python 3.10

Comment: Have you installed PIL? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024397/no-module-named-image

Answer (score 0):

You can (re)install QR Code generator Python package that includes the `Pillow` package for generating images using:

```
pip install qrcode[pil]
```

To install the `Pillow` package individually that include the `Image` class:

```
pip install Pillow
```